# Externally defined SVG markers and filters not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, webkit

I have some SVG filters and markers defined in a separate file for use in my main SVG content.

Here is a sample from the file (dependencies.svg):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <filter id="grayscale">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.6666 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.6666 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.6666 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>

    <marker id="Output" viewBox="0 -6 12 11" refX="10" markerHeight="8" markerWidth="8" orient="auto">
        <path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5L0,-5" stroke-width="1px" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="8" stroke="#696969" style="fill: rgb(105, 105, 105);"></path>
    </marker>
```

The following works in firefox when applied to a line:

```
marker-end: url("/path/to/dependencies.svg#Output");
```

However it does not work in Chrome or Opera.

The same goes for when I try to apply filters to elements such as `<rect>` elements.

The bizarre thing is that I can see my dependencies.svg file being loaded in both cases (firefox and webkit) however webkit does nothing.

I've tested this both as part of the `style` attribute and the `filter` and `marker-end` attributes. In all cases firefox works, Webkit does not.

Is this a known deficiency of Webkit or am I missing something really obvious?

Edit: I guess it could be a Blink issue (I kept saying Webkit, old habit)

Comment: (Confirming) Tried couple of simple testcases and for me it seems like a Blink bug as well. But unlike you I cannot confirm that requests for dependencies initiated by `marker-end`s in Chrome are really sent; I can see them just when using `<use … />` element, what actually works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you were right with "WebKit" wording habit: it is a WebKit bug from 2010:
[References to markers in external SVG documents not applied](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44144). Supposedly it made it to Blink unfixed.

Most recent WebKit SVG bug from 2012: [Make external URL references work](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65344), also open.

Current Blink bug from 2012: [SVG (filter | fill | stroke | clip-path | mask | marker-*) from external files not applied](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212) displays activity so it maybe it could be fixed in 2018 (fingers crossed).

Comment: Yea, I opened up a ticket with the chromium project and it got merged into a Blink ticket that has been open I think since 2012... oh well.

Comment: Cool. Added that issue in description for documentation purposes. Seeing such awkward adoption of nowadays almost ancient SVG standard makes me sad.

Comment: It displays activity in 2021 (fingers still crossed).